# Visual Studio checks out all projects file after enabling of the nuget package restore

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I enabled nuget package restore and now every time I restart VS2013 all project files in my solution(over 200) are checking out. I disabled automatic restore, but it didn't help. Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the .nuget folder in your solution, and look for the file **NuGet.Config**,
in the file change the attribute **disableSourceControlIntegration** value to true or false, according to your needs.